# Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca - "import from file" when setting up VPN

Tags: linux, linux-mint, openvpn

I'm attempting to setup a VPN in Linux Mint 17.1 using the network manager. When I click the + button to add a new connection type, and select VPN, it only lists the option to import files?

I'm lost, because I've done this before on Ubuntu all I needed to do was select OpenVPN as the Connection Type.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: What's the bit that you're stuck on?

Comment: @roaima, thanks for the assistance but with some more fierce googling I managed to finally figure it out! :)

Comment: @timbram can you post what you have done to solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I will do so ASAP as I am mobile now.  I had posted an answer with a link but it looks like someone deleted it or something because they felt it wasn't a good enough answer...